# NSMutableDictionary doesn't initialize correctly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsmutabledictionary

I've encountered a strage error today. I have an `NSArray` and an `NSMutableDictionary`. The problem is that my `NSMutableDictionary` becomes an array. Here's the code:

header:

```
NSArray *tableViewCellValues;
NSMutableDictionary *inputValues;
```

implementation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  tableViewCellValues = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"First", @"Second", @"Third", nil];
  inputValues = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
  //other code...
}
```

So normally I should get an array with "First", "Second" and "Third" as objects and an empty `NSMutableDictionary`. When I print it in the log right after initializing `NSMutableDictionary` I get the following:

```
(lldb) po tableViewCellValues
(NSArray *) $1 = 0x00000000 <nil>
(lldb) po inputValues
(NSMutableDictionary *) $2 = 0x06a80420 <__NSArrayI 0x6a80420>(
First,
Second,
Third
)

(lldb) po [tableViewCellValues class]
error: Couldn't execute function; result was eExecutionDiscarded
(lldb) po [inputValues class]
(id) $4 = 0x01453b64 __NSArrayI
```

I'm kinda confused there. I tried cleaning and running it again, but nothing happens.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.7.3 and Xcode 4.3 if it's important.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried initializing your dictionary by alloc and init? `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`

Comment: @skram I did, but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Are you using ARC? If not, you must retain both the array and the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want to allocate memory for your dictionary, so it should be:

`self.inputValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];`

Comment: Well, you could do that. if it's not a property then just change to `self->inputValues = ...`

Answer (score 1):

The new literal syntax is even better:

```
self.myMutDict = [@{} mutableCopy]
```

or the longer version without property just for understanding:

```
NSDictionary *emptyDict = @{};
NSMutableDictionary *myMutDict = [emptyDict mutableCopy];
```

Comment: As of 2015 this answer is the best

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are not allocate your dictionary

use this code

```
inputValues = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

Comment: sorry, that's not what I want, inputValues should be empty